# layout initialisation peculiarity in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, layout, bootstrapping

I've noticed something interesting about Zend Framework's bootstrap. I created a new project and then used

> zf enable layout

to enable the layout engine. It worked out of the box, woo!

But then I tried creating a function called `_initLayout` in the bootstrap to set some options. Interestingly, this seems to disable the layout again, even if the function body is actually empty. No errors are thrown, but the layout script is not used anymore (exception being the case when I actually set the options again and manually call `Zend_Layout::startMvc()`).

Renaming the function to anything else, like `_initFoo` makes the layout work again.

So, my question is: *is this a function name that is somehow recognised by Zend Framework and extra actions are applied to it, such as cancelling the layout config from application.ini? Are there other cases where I should avoid certain `_init*` function names in the bootstrap?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of the Bootstrap is to setup resources that the application uses. These can either be setup by lines in the config file (`resources.resourcename.foo`) or by methods in the bootstrap class (`_initResourceName()`). I assume `zf enable layout` has added some `resources.layout.*` lines to the application.ini. By adding an `_initLayout` method to the bootstrap, ZF will use this to setup the layout resource *instead* of the configuration lines.

> Are there other cases where I should avoid certain _init* function names in the bootstrap?

The resource plugins are detailed in the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html, `_init<resourcename>()` will always override any corresponding lines in the config.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question in full :).